# Set maximum domain password age in Windows 2008

Tags: active-directory

On a windows 2008 AD controller how can the maximum password age policy be changed, for all domain accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default domain policy has some of the password policies set by default.  This is where you can set the password policies. see [Password Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783512(WS.10).aspx) and for the new features see [Fine grained password policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394(WS.10).aspx)

Prior to Windows Server 2008, you could have only one password and account lockout policy per domain, which applied to all users in the domain. As something new in Windows Server 2008 AD DS, it is now possible to define different sets of password or lockout policies to different set of users in the same domain.